# converting from markdown to pdf corrupts chinese symbols

Tags: pdf, markdown

[here is the pdf file:](https://grzegorzkmita.com/images/grzegorz-kmita-resume-cn.pdf)

[here is a markdown file](https://github.com/Jirafey/Jirafey/blob/main/resumes/grzegorz-kmita-resume-cn.md)

[I used this website to convert](https://dillinger.io/)

Can I do anything to have proper chinese symbols in PDF?

Comment: Try it with pandoc, or an IDE extension that uses pandoc under the hood. There is one for VS Code

Comment: I will try that soon then, great recommendation